# Converting float to string without scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with python / pandas.

My dataframe contains one column called 'id' with 20-digit IDs like `1225485903482773506` with datatype float.
If I convert the column to string with

```
df['id'] = df['id'].apply(str)
```

They come out as something like this `1.289050198535111e+18`

How do I convert them to string without the scientific notation?

Comment: can you print `df.dtypes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply a string formatter to it, instead of just wrapping it in a string. Specifically you can:

```
df["id"].apply("{:.0f}".format)
```

You can simply change "{:.0f}" to "{:.1f}" or "{:.2f}" ... "{:.nf}" to be able to keep 0, 1, 2, ... n decimal places respectively.

Or if you want to see all numbers to the right of the decimal, then this should work:

```
df["id"].apply("{:f}".format)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work: `"{:f}".format(0.000000234234234)` produces `0.000000`.

Comment: If you want more decimal places than the default you can try adding in a larger value to the format-specification: `df["id"].apply("{:.32f}".format)`

Comment: why there is wrong result ：   "{:f}".format(27052805291130213231.64)
=='27052805291130212352.000000'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using the `str()` method? (not tested)

```py
df['id'] = str(df['id'])
```

Comment: This is not correct, since OP wants to convert every individual item from the collum to a string, not the entire thing